# Software to do specific CPU load test

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, performance, cpu-usage, performance-monitor

For the purpose of testing my own script that reports CPU usage I'm looking for a program to put CPU under a certain workload, for instance: 10%, 20%, etc. up to 100%. Is there a program that can do this?

PS. Note that I'm not looking to do a 100% stress test only. I'll need to be able to specify the percent value myself.

Comment: If you have a quad-core then does 10% equate to 10% per core or one core at 40% or 2 cores at 20%?

Comment: Why is this off-topic? I think it's a perfectly legimitate question (and I have the same issue). Programming something like that would need a feedback loop but could be done ... it'd be great if something like that existed.

Answer (score 1):

The first thought that pops into my head would be to run a stress test in a VM and then cap the VMs CPU allocation.

Comment: Good idea. Does VM Ware workstation support it?

Comment: I haven't used VMware in a few years but last I checked it did not.  I know VirtualBox does, and it's free.